# A question on the notion of blocks in BGG category $\mathcal O$

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras, abelian-categories

In his book "Representations of semisimple Lie algebras in BGG category $\mathcal O$" (in this text I'm using notation from this book) J. Humphreys proves the following theorem (it's the proposition 1.13 in his book):

> Let $\lambda$ be an integral weight for semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ (of course, $\lambda \in \mathfrak h^*$) and let $\chi_\lambda$ denote corresponding central character $\chi_\lambda: Z(\mathfrak g) \to \mathbb C$. Then the subcategory $\mathcal O_{\chi_\lambda}$  of the category $\mathcal O$ (for Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$) is $\textit{a block}$.

Here is the proof which is given by Humphreys:

Let $M(\alpha)$ denote a Verma module associated with an arbitrary weight $\alpha$, let $N(\alpha)$ denote its unique maximal proper submodule and let $L(\alpha)$ denote unique simple quotient of $M(\alpha)$, i.e. $M(\alpha)/N(\alpha)$.

From the previous chapter, it follows that it just has to be shown that all modules $L(w \cdot \lambda)$ (for all possible $w$ in Weyl group of algebra $\mathfrak g$) lie in the same block. Using a simple induction argument we can see that it's enough to prove that for every integral weight $\lambda$ and for every simple reflection $s_\alpha$ modules $L(\lambda)$ and $L(s_\alpha \cdot \lambda)$ lie in the came block (Warning: here $s_\alpha \cdot \lambda$ means the so-called **dot-product**: $s_\alpha \cdot \lambda = s_\alpha(\lambda + \rho) - \rho$, where $\rho$ is the half-sum of all positive roots for adjoint action of Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$).

So we'll now prove that $L(\lambda)$ and $L(s_\alpha \cdot \lambda)$ are in the same block. Let $\mu$ denote $s_\alpha \cdot \lambda$. We can assume that $\mu \leq \lambda$ (if $\mu > \lambda$ we can reverse the roles of $\lambda$ and $\mu$). In the previous part of the book was proven the fact that in this case there is a non-zero homomorphism $\phi: M(\mu) \to M(\lambda)$ such that $N(\lambda)$ contains $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)$.

Let $N$ denote $\phi(N(\mu))$. Now we see that $\phi: M(\mu) \to M(\lambda)$ induces a morphism $\psi:L(\mu) = M(\mu) / N(\mu) \to M(\lambda)/N$. Moreover, $\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)$ is a proper submodule of $M(\mu)$ so $\operatorname{Ker}(\phi) \subset N(\mu)$. Thus $\psi$ is an embedding.

After that Humphreys says that from this fact it follows that $L(\mu)$ and $L(\lambda)$ are in the same block of category $\mathcal O$. Why? Can someone, please, explain to me this fact?

It would be clear if $L(\lambda)$ was isomorphic to $(M(\lambda)/N)/\psi(L(\lambda)) = (M(\lambda)/N)/\operatorname{Im}(\psi) \simeq M(\lambda)/\operatorname{Im}(\phi)$, but I don't see why this fact could be true...

Comment: Let $S$ be the sum of all submodules $T$ of $M(\lambda)/N$ such that $L(\lambda)$ and $L(\mu)$ are not composition series factors of $T$.  Prove that $J=\frac{M(\lambda)/N}{S}$ is indecomposable with composition series $0\subset L(\mu) \subset L(\mu)^2 \subset \ldots \subset L(\mu)^k \subset J$ for some positive integer $k$.  This shows that $\operatorname{Ext}^1\big(L(\lambda),L(\mu)\big)\ne 0$.

Comment: Just realized that $L(\mu)$ may occur more than once.

Comment: Not a problem, you just mod everything out by $L(\mu)^{k-1}$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Could you explain to me, please, why the composition series cant't has any terms except $J$ and powers of $L(\mu)$?

Comment: For each composition series factor $L(\nu)$ of $M(\lambda)/N$, you can measure the *distance* $d(\nu,\lambda)$ by the smallest number of simple reflections $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_k$ such that $$\nu=(s_{\alpha_k}s_{\alpha_{k-1}}\cdots s_{\alpha_1})\cdot \lambda \leq \ldots \leq s_{\alpha_1}\cdot\lambda \leq \lambda.$$  That is, $d(\mu,\lambda)=1$.  $d(\nu,\lambda)=1$ and $\nu\neq \mu$, or if $d(\nu,\lambda)>1$, then $L(\nu)$ is a composition factor of some submodule with highest weight $\nu$, which is a submodule of $S$.

Comment: Consequently, the only composition series factors of $M(\lambda)/N$ that are not in $S$ are $L(\lambda)$ and $L(\mu)$ (although we might have many copies of $L(\mu)$).  However, since extensions of $L(\mu)$ are trivial, the socle structure of $J=\frac{ M(\lambda)/N}{S}$ is $$\begin{array}{|c|}\hline L(\lambda)\\ \hline L(\mu)\oplus L(\mu) \oplus \ldots \oplus L(\mu)\\\hline\end{array}.$$  Note that $J$ is indecomposable since it is generated by a single vector with weight $\lambda$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I'm very sorry for my stupidity but I still don't understand your argument.

In your first comment, you say that $L(\nu)$ is a composition factor of some submodule with the highest weight $\nu$. Could you, please, explain how to construct this submodule? And one more thing isn't clear to me: you're talking about both composition series of $M(\lambda)/N$ and $(M(\lambda)/N)/S$. How do you get the second from the first? What do you mean when you're saying that "composition series factor is in $S$"? Isn't a composition series factor a quotient of two submodules?

Comment: Let $L(\nu)$ be a composition factor of $M(\lambda)$.  We want to show that $L(\nu)$ is a composition factor (in fact the head) of a h.w. submodule of $M(\lambda)$ with h.w. $\nu$.  This result passes on to any quotient of $M(\lambda)$.  We induct on the length of $M(\lambda)$.  If $M(\lambda)$ is simple, then $\nu=\lambda$ and $L(\nu)=M(\nu)=M(\lambda)$, so that $L(\nu)$ is a composition factor of the h.w. module $M(\nu)$ with h.w. $\nu$.  From now, assume that $M(\lambda)$ is not simple.

Comment: If $\nu=\lambda$, then we are done.  If $\nu <\lambda$, then $L(\nu)$ is a composition factor of $N(\lambda)$, which is the sum of all proper Verma submodules of $M(\lambda)$.  We can then assume that $L(\nu)$ is a composition factor of one of these Verma submodule $M(\lambda')$.   By induction, $L(\nu)$ is a composition factor of some h.w. submodule of $M(\lambda')$ with h.w. $\nu$.

Comment: By "composition series factor in $S$" I mean the composition series factor arises as a composition series factor of a submodule of $S$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Thank you very much for your explanation! But how do you derive the fact that there aren't any composition series factors which arise both in some submodule of $S$ and in $(M(\lambda)/N)/S$? And is there, more generally, a way to describe composition series factors of $(M(\lambda)/N)/S$ using comp. series factors of $(M(\lambda)/N)$?

Comment: The composition series factors of $J$ are obtained from that of $M(\lambda)/N$ by keeping $L(\lambda)$ and all copies of $L(\mu)$.  That's it.  And there aren't anything else in $J$ because all other $L(\nu)$ appear as composition factors of $S$ due to the construction of $S$.  That is why $J$ and $S$ do not share composition factors.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Your patience is unbelievable!! Thank you. But my question was slightly different from that you've answered... Is there a result describing composition series factors of an arbitrary quotient module $A / B$ if comp. series factors of $B$ are given? If there is one, could you give me a link, please? If there isn't any, why are you saying that the comp. series factors of J are obtained from $M(\lambda)/N$ by keeping $L(\lambda)$ and all of the copies of $L(\mu)$?

Comment: For a h.w. module $M$, we can do something similar.   Let $Y$ be a subset of $\mathfrak{h}^*$ which satisfies the property that if $\lambda \in Y$ and if $s$ is a simple reflection such that $s\cdot \lambda \leq \lambda$, then $s\cdot\lambda \in Y$.  If $S$ is the sum of submodules of $M$ with composition series factors of the form $L(\lambda)$ with $\lambda \in Y$, then the composition factors of $M/S$ is obtained from the composition factors of $M$ by removing all $L(\lambda)$ with $\lambda \in Y$.

Comment: Regarding your last question, you should probably need to read the definitions of $J$ and $S$ again, and see from my previous comments that taking quotient by $S$ of $M(\lambda)/N$ takes away every composition factor except $L(\lambda)$ and $L(\mu)$.

Comment: I am not sure about your question regarding $A/B$.  But I think this is just the Jordan-Holder theorem.  If you know composition factors of $A$ and $B$, then the composition factors of $A/B$ is just the composition factors of $A$ after you remove those that appear as composition factors of $B$.